# Android update progressBar on RecyclerView rows

Tags: android

I'm trying to find any good document and tutorial to update progress percent when i attach that on `recyclerView` items, for example like with this screen shot:

[image]

[image]

i can't find any document about update `progressbar` on `recycleview`

Comment: What do you have so far? Have you been able to display a percentage for a single item?

Comment: @Bryan yes, you suppose i want to show percentage and update progress bar for a single item

Comment: Can we do it by use of glide ?

Answer (score -3):

If you use Glide you can set `placeholder` (only image, without progress percent).

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-placeholders-fade-animations

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

// ... ...

Glide  
    .with(context)
    .load(stringURL)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholder)
    .into(imageView);

}
```